# Google app engine fails on OSX Lion with python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, osx-lion

I am using Google App Engine and just updated to Lion on my mac. I am using eclipse with Pydev. Now as soon as I updated I have been unable to launch the dev server. I get the stack trace below. Anyone else with the same problem?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 76, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 72, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_main.py", line 142, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/tempfile.py", line 34, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/random.py", line 45, in <module>
    from math import log as _log, exp as _exp, pi as _pi, e as _e, ceil as _ceil
ImportError: dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/math.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyLong_AsScaledDouble
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/math.so
```

Comment: did you try updating to a new version of google app engine, is there one?

Comment: GAE automatically prompts you to upgrade, so that's probably not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up uninstalling GAE and eclipse and reinstalling. It works now.

From looking at the stack trace it seems like the PyDev plugin was the culprit

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I just pointed my library stuff to 2.7 in the same root, e.g. 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/...
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/... 
and everything worked fine again. Looks like the binaries 2.6 was built on are not compiled for Lion.
Found in Preferences-> PyDev-> Interpreter - Python-> Libraries